# How to wait for async task in a List of KeyValuePairs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have the following code...

```
List<Task<KeyValuePair<string, SomeLongWaitingResponse>>> LongWaitedResponses
    = new List<Task<KeyValuePair<string, SomeLongWaitingResponse>>>();

foreach(var request in requests)
{
    async Task<KeyValuePair<string, SomeLongWaitingResponse>> func()
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<string, SomeLongWaitingResponse>(requestId,
            await _service.SomeLongWaitingRequest(request));
    }
    LongWaitedResponses.Add(func());
}

var result = await Task.WhenAll(LongWaitedResponses);
```

How do I wait for all `LongWaitedResponses` to finish? I want to wait for all of them and then continue with execution. Problem I encounter is that my `WhenAll` continues even `SomeLongWaitingResponse` has not come.

Comment: I did a test myself by writing my own `SomeLongWaitingRequest()` method that just does a `Task.Delay()`, and I was not able to reproduce your problem. So I suspect your problem has to do with something inside whatever `_service.SomeLongWaitingRequest(request)` is doing.

Comment: Could you show us where is all this code located? Is it inside a method? If yes, how and where do you call that method?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Yes, it is called in the method which is doing more stuff that I would prefer but I don't have control on that part. Method is async itself if you are refering to that... This requests are also dependable on async method which is supposed to return data for second request. And it looks like - getDataForRequest = await _someOtherService.GetData();  I am pretty sure that logic works because when in debugging mode it works as intended...I have logged for myself data after WhenAll and would get <List<KeyValuePair<CorrectId, null>,...>.

Comment: But the think I will try is to log the request data, just in case. Thank you for an idea

Comment: My suspicion is that you are invoking an async method in a fire-and-forget fashion, somewhere down the stack.

Comment: Thanks guys. It was one of those errors.... Uri of the external api was changed. Guys changed it in the debugging configuration but forgot a pre-prod config. And there we go. 4 hours of debugging for nothing. Thank you all